# Limit Openlayer map for a single Map instead of rendering infinitely

Tags: openlayers

When using a tile source, Openlayers renders the image repeatedly. Is there a way to limit it to a single image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tile sources (TileWMS, XYZ, etc.) have a wrapX constructor option.

Set it to false to render 'one world'.